# C++ Move Semantics

Tags: c++

I have this example:

```
Widget* makeWidget(int a, int b) {
if (a > b) {
    return new Widget(a);   
}
else {
    return new  Widget(b);  
 }
}
```

Isn't that the same like Moving the return values, because you just pass the reference and not a copy? Why do I end  Moving Constructor/Assignemnt ?

Greetings

Comment: Why not this way: `Widget* makeWidget(int a, int b) { return new Widget(a > b ? a : b); }` In C++ the `?:` operator may even handle references. I.e. I 've used it even for conditional calls of constructors (themselves) for initialization of instances.

Comment: @Scheff absolutely irrelevant to the question at hand. It's clearly just an example.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz If the questioner didn't consider that a (raw) pointer assignment doesn't mean any move semantics he might have missed other (even simpler) opportunities also...

Comment: Also [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11540204/752976)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I end Moving Constructor/Assignemnt ?

In your function:

```
Widget* makeWidget(int a, int b);
```

You are returning a `Widget *` (i.e.: a *pointer* to `Widget`) no *move* of an object takes place here at all.

---

> Isn't that the same like Moving the return values, because you just pass the reference and not a copy?

It is not the same in terms of semantics, because by moving you always return an object.

By moving you are actually not copying, but *moving* the data from the *move-from* object (i.e.: the object being moved) to the *move-to* object (i.e.: the object being constructed or assigned to by means of the *move constructor* or *move assignment operator*, respectively).

Comment: @GillBates A raw pointer cannot be moved (or more precisely, moving a raw pointer is no different to copying it).

Comment: @Walter mhmm, there's no benefit out of it but I just noted it to keep OP aware of semantics with return statements. You're right it has no use here though.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you compare it with. If you've replaced the return type with `unique_ptr<Widget>`, you'd use the move constructor to achieve clear ownership semantics.

Compared to plain `Widget` return, if you did that you'd also achieve non-nullability.

In your case no move is performed, but you also don't have any benefits. You return something that can be null with no ownership specification. Without a move constructor you can either do that, or be forced to copy to maintain proper semantics and guarantees. Move constructors allow you to have that cake and eat it, too.

Comment: Though in this case returning a `unique_ptr<Widget>` via `std::move()` may suppress RVO.

Comment: @Walter You don't generally need `::std::move()` in return statements since conversion to rvalue is automatic when a value is returned.